# R: Using kappam.fleiss while ignoring NA?

Tags: r

I have a dataset similar to the below:

```
zz <-  "Rater1    Rater2    Rater3     
1          1         0         1 
2          1         0         NA
3          0         1         1
4          NA        0         0
5          0         1         0
6          1         1         0
7          NA        0         0
8          0         NA        0
9          1         1         1  
10         1         0         0"

data <- read.table(text=zz, header = TRUE)
```

Using the `irr` [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/irr/irr.pdf), I'd like to find the `kappam.fleiss` value for the dataset. This code gets me that, but excludes the rows with an NA (you'll note only six observations in the output as oppossed to the desired ten):

```
kappam.fleiss(data, exact = FALSE, detail = FALSE)
```

So, how can I get the 'kappam.fleiss' results using all ten rows; i.e., ommitting NA values individually instead of listwise?

Just returning the list of 8 values from 'kappam.fleiss' that includes data from each row is enough. Thanks to @Paul Hiemstra for the note on clarification.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish. The result of `kappam.fleisch` is a list of 8 values. When you assign this to the `data.frame`, what do you want happening?

Comment: @PaulHiemstra, I'd like to just **know** the kappa value (the fifth value) -- no need to put into df. So, just having the list of values w/ the noted NA treatment is good enough. Assignment to a df is a leftover from an edit which I now see was confusing to leave in -- I'll edit again.

Comment: `kappam.fleiss(data, exact = FALSE, detail = FALSE)$value` gives you the kappa value as far as I can tell. Is this what you needed?

Comment: @PaulHiemstra, not quite. That value only gives me the kappa for the six rows that do not have an 'NA'. I also want the kappa for the rows with an NA, where just the NA value is excluded from the analysis instead of the listwise omission that is standard to 'kappam.fleiss'. So, a kappa based on 10 rows, not 6.